# How to add distortion and edit font for captcha generation in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, captcha

I have a code written in php of captcha generation, but it doesnt have distortions and enough difficulty.

I have a simple code of php captcha generator.

Output captcha:

[image]

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

[image]

How could i possibly do, first of all holes in between borders of letters or number and how to make this type of distortion (like liquify in photoshop)? As far as i know vector field has to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by searching scripts of captcha generators on the net. First of all, to add the desirable letter form you have to find on the internet fonts with open spaces (in this case something like Cathedral open font will be enough).
To create distortions i found captcha generator named “kcaptcha”, which makes all this process fairly simple, even if you don't know php